# SalesForce Case object not showing up under object settings in my permission set

Tags: permissions, salesforce

It's showing up for other permission sets but not for mine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the permission set is limited to particular license. If you're on Chatter Plus or say Platform user - you can see only certain standard objects